# How to extract elements of an array with a fixed step (matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

I'm pretty new at coding with Matlab and I'm struggling with an issue I can't fix.
Basically I have data "half - hourly taken" (48 per day) and referred to 17 days (17x48=816 elements).
I got all my data in a big matrix (816 x 31)and I need to discriminate some "day time data" from "night time data".
The elements of the column array (816 elements) I need to process are the following (for the first day):

night_data= bigmatrix([1:8,46:48],27);

day_data= bigmatrix([22:32],27)

but I have to make the same "selection" for each day, i.e. the next day would be

night_data_2 = bigmatrix ([49:56,93:96],27)

day_data_2 = bigmatrix ([70:81],27)

and so on...
How can I make it? Should I use a loop? Is there any indexing function I don't know that could help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reshape your data so that each column represents one day. That would give you a 48 x 17 x 31 matrix:

```
dailymatrix = reshape(bigmatrix, 48, 17, 31);
```

Now, to access the data you've got one new subscript. Your first night/day data would change to

```
night_data = dailymatrix([1:8, 46:48], 1, 27);
                                   %   ^-- 1st day
day_data = dailymatrix([22:32], 1, 27);
```

The second day's data would be:

```
night_data = dailymatrix([1:8, 46:48], 2, 27);
                                   %   ^-- 2nd day
day_data = dailymatrix([22:32], 2, 27);
```

To get all 17 days' worth of data,

```
night_data = dailymatrix([1:8, 46:48], :, 27);
day_data = dailymatrix([22:32], :, 27);
```

Since the data is in the same timeslots each day, you never have to change the first subscript.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables in your indicies for your matrix and wrap this in a loop with some dynamic indexing.

```
night_data.(strcat('night',int2str(n)))=bigmatrix([1+n*48:8+n*48, 46+n*48:48+n*48],27)
```

This will create a structure that creates fields called night 1, night 2 etc all the way to night n that you need. This can be repeated for day as well.

However, you should be using date indexing with table variables in matlab. Once you convert your date column to a datetime object,

```
bigmatrix.Date=datetime(bigmatrix.Date)
```

you can basically do something like the following.

```
night_data_1=bigmatrix(hour(bigmattrix.Date)>22&hour(bigmattrix.Date)<8 ,27)
```

which will be able to index all data points between 10 PM and 8 AM (or whatever your day-night cycle cutoff is).